# WPF C# DatePicker open calendar on click

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker, wpf-controls

I am adding a WPF `DatePicker` control to my form and it works fine. But I don't want the user to be able to type in a type in the 'Select a date' textbox. I want that to be readonly and when they click the textbox it just opens the calendar.

I wasn't sure if there was an option for this in the properties? I couldn't find anything...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <DatePicker.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DatePickerTextBox">
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Text" Value=" "/>
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
        </Style>
    </DatePicker.Resources>
</DatePicker>
```

In future you can use the WPF visualizer to see which child controls a top-level control is using (in this case DatePickerTextBox) and then apply a style and/or template to that type in the resources section like I've done here.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution! I will use the WPF visualizer if I run into a similar problem.

Comment: my datepicker was acting very odd because of opening the calendar on hover , and i searched the whole internet and finally found this , you saved my day thank you !

Answer (score 5):

The answer of Mark Feldman is partially right, he had not answer to how clicking on the textbox gonna open the calendare popup!

You should hook the template of the `DatePicker` and enlarge the size of the button so it will overlap the textbox: then you are done, when you click on the textbox it's the button that get the event see below a part of the modified template of `DatePicker`:

```
<DatePickerTextBox Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="0" x:Name="PART_TextBox" Focusable="{TemplateBinding Focusable}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
<Button Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="0" x:Name="PART_Button"  Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Focusable="False" >
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border Background="Transparent"/>
                <Button Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Template="{StaticResource DropDownButtonTemplate}"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20" Margin="3,0,3,0" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Dont forget to add the style of `DatePickerTextBox` described in the answer of Mark Feldman

Comment: thanks for this. I've been struggling with this one, nice solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can open calendar this way :

```
<DatePicker Name="datePicker" Focusable="False">
     <DatePicker.Resources>
          <Style TargetType="DatePickerTextBox">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonUp" Handler="OnMouseLeftButtonUp" />
          </Style>
     </DatePicker.Resources>
</DatePicker>
```

```
private void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    datePicker.IsDropDownOpen = true;
}
```